# Send JSON and Image with single request. Angular + Spring Boot

Tags: spring, angular, typescript, spring-boot

**Spring Rest Controller**

```
@PostMapping(
    value = "/post",
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
    consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE}
)
public ResponseEntity<User> handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("user") User user, @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
    // do something with User and file
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

**Angular Service**

```
@Injectable()
export class UploadFileService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  pushFileToStorage(file: File): Observable<HttpEvent<{}>> {
    let formdata: FormData = new FormData();
    formdata.append('file', file);
    formdata.append('user', JSON.stringify(new User('John', 12)))

    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', '/post', formdata, {
      reportProgress: true,
    });

    return this.http.request(req);
  }
}
```

When I try to send the request I get **`500 Internal Server Error.`**

**Here's a request header**

```
POST /post HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4200
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 152881
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarydaQb5yaWw2xu1V9r
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

**Request payload**

```
------WebKitFormBoundarydaQb5yaWw2xu1V9r
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Screen Shot 2017-10-24 at 8.49.13 PM.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundarydaQb5yaWw2xu1V9r
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user"

{"name":"John","age":12}
------WebKitFormBoundarydaQb5yaWw2xu1V9r--
```

Note: If in Spring rest controller I change parameter type User to String it works.

Question: How to send request from Angular so that on Spring I can get User and MultipartFile, instead of String.

Comment: I am using Angular 4 and Spring Boot 1.5.7

Comment: Did you find any solution for this error ?. I'm getting the same, please support.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Changing

```
public ResponseEntity<User> handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("user") User user, @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file)
```

to

```
public ResponseEntity<User> handleFileUpload(@RequestPart("user") User user, @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file)
```

and changing the request to something like this will work:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
-F 'user={"name":"John","age":12};type=application/json' \
-F "file=@myfile.txt" http://localhost:8080/post
```

For `consumes` only `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE` is required.

To make above kind of request in angular, something like this can be done:

```
const userBlob = new Blob(JSON.stringify(new User('John', 12)),{ type: "application/json"});
formdata.append('user', userBlob);
```

Comment: I tried the same, but I'm getting,  Failed to convert request element: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'com.PersonDTO'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'com.PersonDTO': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Comment: @dinesh Can you post your code in a separate question?

Comment: ,Please refer the below..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50462894/upload-a-json-object-user-information-and-multiple-image-with-single-request

Comment: I tried your proposition, you need to add `[]` to `JSON.stringify(new User('John', 12)`:

`const myObjStr = JSON.stringify(new User('John', 12);
const userBlob = new Blob([myObjStr],{ type: "application/json"});`

Comment: It depends upon how you want your JSON and the data model used at the backend. Both with or without `[]` are valid JSON and should work fine if we have the right data model to handle it.